# making dynamically added DIVs be droppable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm having a problem making a dynamically added div the target for my drag and drop operations If someone could examine this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dgobrien123/FvG2J/embedded/result/
and possibly assist me in finding my error.

In the document ready method, this is how the droppable is applied:

```
        $(".droppable").droppable({
            activeClass: 'dragactive',
            hoverClass: 'drophover',
            drop: function(event, ui) {                    
                alert( this.id );
                $(this).addClass('drophighlight').find('p').text( '' + ui.draggable.children("span").text() + '');
            }
        });
```

Here is how the container is added:

```
    function addGroup() {
        counter = counter + 1;
        $("div#pcgroups").append("<div class='dropcontainer'><div class='droppable' id='GROUP" + counter + "'><p>PC GROUP #" + counter + "</p></div></div>");
        return counter;
    }
```

Comment: For future reference, including a fiddle is great, keep doing that. But also include the relevant code in the question so in case the the fiddle goes away this question still has meaningful content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are applying the droppable before your elements are created.  You can apply it as they are created in your addGroup() method:

```
function addGroup() {
    counter = counter + 1;
    var x = $("<div class='dropcontainer'><div class='droppable' id='GROUP" + counter + "'><p>PC GROUP #" + counter + "</p></div></div>");

    $("div#pcgroups").append(x);
    x.droppable({
        activeClass: 'dragactive',
        hoverClass: 'drophover',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            alert(this.id);
            $(this).addClass('drophighlight').find('p').text('' + ui.draggable.children("span").text() + '');
        }
    });
}
```

Updated Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/johnkoer/FvG2J/28/